# Declarative Models of Computation in Physical Machines

Tags: prolog, lambda-calculus, computation

I've been studying Models of computation lately and i came up with a question.

For many models of computation, it seems like it is possible to implement them in physical machines. Some in fact, are actually based on physical entities.

For instance, that is the case with Imperative Models of Computation like Automatas ( FSM, PDA and Turing Machine ), Post-Machines, RAM Machine.    This is also the case with Quantum computing and Bio Computing.

But for some models of computation, i've never seen indications that they could be implemented directly by physical machines.  For example, the Functional Model of Computation ( Lambda Calculus ) and Logic Model of Computaiton ( fragment of first-order logic ).
In theory , however, it seems possible ... we would just need to simulate functions and beta-reductions in the physical machine. For the Logic MoC, it seems even harder, though.

Does anyone have an idea about implementations of Functional MoC and Logic MoC in physical machines ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Both functional and logic programming languages do run on physical machines in a quite similar way as current imperative programming languages. There is no 1-to-1 correspondence to, say the RAM machine, either way.

Comment: At first blush, I'd have to agree with @false. At the machine level, functional and logic programming operate effectively with mostly the same "primitives". Although, given the recursive nature of a language such as Prolog, it *might* benefit from an architecture optimized for stacks (*e.g.*, the old HP minicomputers).

Comment: I'm talking about really going all the way to the bottom. I think all machines will eventually get down to logic gates and memory ( flipflops ) acting together with a clock, which is exactly imperative model of computation.   I'm talking about whether it is possible to have a machine ( the bottom level ) implementing functional and logic MoC directly, that is, no flipflops and memory, at least, and no logic gates.

Answer (score 0):

The standard for Prolog is the WAM. Its an acronym for Warren Abstract
Machine. It devices a set of instructions and a receipt to compile
Prolog to these instructions.

But additionally one can also easily see how these instructions can 
be realized in machine code of a simple register machine.

In practice there are Prolog systems based on WAM that generate code 
for real existing CPUs. Although WAM is not the only approach to
implement a Prolog interpreter:

Recommended reading:

David H. D. Warren (October 1983).
  An abstract Prolog instruction set.
  Menlo Park, CA, USA: Artificial Intelligence Center at SRI International.

Hassan Aït-Kaci (February 18, 1999).
  Warren's Abstract Machine: A Tutorial Reconstruction.
  Archived from the original on 2003-02-13.

You find working links here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warren_Abstract_Machine

Bye